# Efficient data structure to store subsets of a graph

Tags: data-structures, graph, subset

I have derived some subsets of a graph.Now I want to store this subsets and label them such as subset_1,subset_2 etc.Which data structure would be efficient to do that?
This is the main graph

[image]

The circled marks are the subsets

[image]

Comment: It depends on what operations will be done on the container of subsets.   For example will you want to efficiently determine how large each subset is?  Or if a particular node is in the same subset as another particular node?  Or whether there are any intersections?  Or whether the subsets together cover all the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subgraph is actually a graph. You can use Graph to store these subsets/subgraph.